# Gremlin query works in TinkerGraph, JanusGraph and Neo4j but not in DSE Graph 6.8.1

Tags: gremlin, datastax, tinkerpop, janusgraph, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have the following query which works without any issues with TinkerGraph, JanusGraph and Neo4j-Gremlin:

```
g.V().has('Account','address','0x0').
    out('sent').has('eventName','Transfer').as('t1').
    out('received_by').has('type','EOA').has('status','Active').as('a2').
    out('sent').has('eventName','Transfer').as('t2').
    where('t1',eq('t2')).by('address').
    where('t1',eq('t2')).by('amount').
    out('received_by').has('type','EOA').has('status','Active').as('a3').
    select('a3','a2').
        by('address').
    group().
        by('a3').
        by('a2').
    unfold().
    where(select(values).limit(local,2).count(local).is(gte(2).and(lte(1000))))
```

But with DataStax Graph I get the following error:

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element
```

I know the issue is after the select but I haven't been able to figure out in which point is really failing. Any ideas would help. Thanks.

Comment: What version of DSE Graph are you using?

Comment: Could you please also share an excerpt from your system.log? It should contain a stack trace with a ClassCastException

Comment: @bechbd I am using DSE Graph 6.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataStax Graph 6.8.1 uses an early release of TinkerPop 3.4.5. That release does not contain [the full release feature](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.7/upgrade/#_by_string_modulator) that allows `by(String)` to work on a `Map`. You should be able to re-write your traversal to:

```
g.V().has('Account','address','0x0').
    out('sent').has('eventName','Transfer').as('t1').
    out('received_by').has('type','EOA').has('status','Active').as('a2').
    out('sent').has('eventName','Transfer').as('t2').
    where('t1',eq('t2')).by('address').
    where('t1',eq('t2')).by('amount').
    out('received_by').has('type','EOA').has('status','Active').as('a3').
    select('a3','a2').
        by('address').
    group().
        by(select('a3')).
        by(select('a2').fold()).
    unfold().
    where(select(values).limit(local,2).count(local).is(gte(2).and(lte(1000))))
```

Comment: Re-writing the query like this did the trick, thanks a lot.